# Finding the derivative of powers using First Principles

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am unsure how to differentiate $f(x)=x^{\frac34}$ using **first principles** definition of the derivative.

I appreciate any help.

Chris

Comment: The ... first ... principles? Do you mean the definition of the derivative?

Comment: Not really, more seeking help in how to apply the first principles with this particular question.

Comment: It seems that there is confusion with what you mean by first principles. What are these first principles aside from the definition of derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The first principles definition of the derivative is given by
$$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

In your case, let $f(x)=x^{\frac34}$.  Then, the limit becomes
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^{\frac34}-x^{\frac34}}{h}
\end{align}

Observe what happens when we conjugate the numerator:
$$
\frac{(x+h)^{\frac34}-x^{\frac34}}{h}\color{blue}{\cdot\frac{(x+h)^{\frac34}+x^{\frac34}}{(x+h)^{\frac34}+x^{\frac34}}}=\frac{(x+h)^{\frac32}-x^{\frac32}}{h\big({(x+h)^{\frac34}+x^{\frac34}}\big)}
$$

What would happen if you were to conjugate the numerator again?
$$
\frac{(x+h)^{\frac32}-x^{\frac32}}{h\big({(x+h)^{\frac34}+x^{\frac34}}\big)}\color{blue}{\cdot\frac{(x+h)^{\frac32}+x^{\frac32}}{(x+h)^{\frac32}+x^{\frac32}}}=\frac{(x+h)^3-x^3}{h\big({(x+h)^{\frac34}+x^{\frac34}}\big)\big((x+h)^{\frac32}+x^{\frac32}\big)}
$$
The numerator can now be expanded, and you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Sorry, I am having a bit of trouble understanding how you get (x+h)^3/4 when conjugating the numerator

Comment: Using the algorithm for conjugating based on the factorization of a difference of squares:  $$(a-b)\color{blue}{(a+b)}=a^2-b^2.$$
Specifically for this example, it is also a good idea to consider that  $$(a^m-b^n)\color{blue}{(a^m+b^n)}=a^{2m}-b^{2n}.$$

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. Thanks for the reply. I will try figure out the result of an additional conjugation :)

Comment: Strangely, I got a 0 for the numerator, when i conjugated it again. Is that what i should be aiming to do, or would there be some error in my calculation?

Comment: Added the conjugation in an edit to my answer.  There must have been some error in your calculation, or you did not write the correct conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

Compute $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[4]{(x+h)^3}-\sqrt[4]{x^3}}{h}$$ if $h\ne 0$

Comment: Couldn't edit your post, but perhaps you meant $\sqrt[4]{\color{blue}{x}^3}$ instead?

Comment: Thank you, just corrected!

Answer (score 0):

We Know That The Derivative of $f(x)$ is Given by $f(x+h)-f(x)\over h$

Since $f(x) = x^{3\over 4}$

Derivative is Given By : $f(x+h)^{3\over 4} - f(x)^{3\over 4}\over h$

Using Bionomial Theroem , derivative= $1\over h$ [$(x^{3\over 4 }$ + ${3\over 4} x^{-1\over4}h$  +other terms containing higher power of h ) - $x^{3\over4}$ ]

= $1\over h $[${3\over4} x^{-1\over4}h$ + other Terms containing higher power of h ]

=${3\over4}x^{-1\over4}$ + other  Terms containing higher power of h

=${3\over4}x^{-1\over4}$

Hence Derivative of $x^{3\over4}$ Is ${3\over4}x^{-1\over4}$